# Saving a video capture in python with openCV : empty video

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture

I'm new in Python (2.7) and I try to work on video processing (with module openCv "cv2"). Starting with tutorials, I try to use the script of [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html) : paragraph "Saving a video". 
Everything works fine excepting that **the video I'm saving is empty**. **I can find output.avi in my directory but its memory size is 0kb** an, of course when I run it, no video is displayed.

After a few changes here is my code :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
#fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')
fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'DIVX')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:

        # write the flipped frame
        out.write(frame)

        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Does anyone know why it is not working properly ?

Thanks a lot.
Edwin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I never worked with openCV, but I bet the problem is in

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

This is a C version of the VideoCapture method http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture

Maybe you can try to do the same. Something like

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if (not cap.isOpened()):
    print "Error"
```

EDIT: just downloaded Python and OpenCV and discovered the problem was the codec. Try to change

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))
```

for

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', -1, 20.0, (640,480))
```

and select the codec by hand.

Comment: To Sauruxum : Hi, Thanks for your answer. I tried this, Cap.isOpened() returns True actually. I can even see the capture in live so it does get in the while loop. Thank you though. That could have been the problem.

Comment: Sorry. I'm dumb and I didn't see you used indeed that method. But still, if you passed that method ( you can see the camera feedback ) and you are getting no video file then something on the loop is not working. It's not like you are getting a back video whit X frames; the frames are not being saved on the file so you have a 0kB file. Or could be the codec?

Comment: To Sauruxum : You are right. There is something wrong in the loop. It does get in the loop but does not save. I know nothing about codec. What is it ? What can be wrong with it ? cheers.

Comment: I just downloaded openCV and Python. I knew was the coded. Try to replace out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480)) for out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', -1, 20.0, (640,480)) and select by hand the codec you have. I edited the answer.

Comment: It works ! Wonderful. Thank you for having downloaded python + openCv for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could be the output resolution is different from the input. Check width and height of cap.

```
size = (int(cap.get(3)), int(cap.get(4)))
```

Change either your camera or the output resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I have Windows 10, Python3.7.6, OpenCV 4.2.0. In my case, the problem is video encoder. Both `"XVID"` and `"X264"` result in an empty output video. I changed the encoder to `"DIVX"` and the video is generated successfully.